# React - Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am new to React. I am trying to accomplish something like this:

On clicking a button, some fetches are performed, and then a modal is automatically rendered. A second button press should not be required to render the modal.

I am using the modal example from the official React-Bootstrap website (with some modifications). I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Target container is not a DOM element.
    at render (react-dom.development.js:26091:1)
    at startGame (StartGame.jsx:30:1)
```

This is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal'
import { render } from 'react-dom';

function StartGame (props) {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  const [sessionId, setSessionId] = React.useState(null);
  const quizId = props.data;
  const startGame = async () => {
    const init = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    }
    await fetch(`http://localhost:5005/admin/quiz/${quizId}/start`, init);
    const init2 = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    }
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5005/admin/quiz/${quizId}`, init2);
    const output = await response.json();
    setSessionId(output.active);
    console.log(sessionId);
    render(<Example />);
  }
  return (
    <>
    <button onClick={startGame}>Start</button>
    </>
  );
}

function Example () {
  const [show, setShow] = React.useState(true);

  const handleClose = () => setShow(false);

  return (
    <>
      <Modal show={show} onHide={handleClose}>
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Modal heading</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>Hello there</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <button onClick={handleClose}>
            Close
          </button>
          <button onClick={handleClose}>
            Save Changes
          </button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}

StartGame.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.number
};

export default StartGame;
```

I am not sure why this is happening, and how I can fix it. I went through loads of online tutorials/examples, but can't find anything that caters to my needs.

Please help.

Comment: Did you look up the API of `render` to see if you're using it correctly (you're not)? Also this is not how you'd typically render a modal, you would use [createPortal](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using React <= 17: `ReactDOM.render` takes two arguments: the first is the JSX Element to render and the second is the HTML DOM element in which you want to render.

Usually, people do like this:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

In case you're using React 18:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('root');
const root = ReactDOMClient.createRoot(container);

root.render(<App />);
```

---

P.-S. If you want to render your JSX Element into an html string, you can use [renderToStaticMarkup](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html) like this:

```js
const myHtmlString = ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(<App />);
```